# MySQL join to same table

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I've got one table (called staging) with the following relevant fields:

```
id (PRIMARY)
bundle_id (INT)
product (enum H,L,D)
bundle_code (enum 10,20)
```

I need to search for a bundle_id where the bundle_code is 10, then also retrieve any other records with the same bundle_id where product = H and up to two additional records with the same bundle_id where product != H.  I'm trying to do this all in one query, returning one row per bundle_id; so I have a list of bundle_ids, each containing every product and id attached to that bundle_id.

The best I've come up with is this:

```
SELECT e1.bundle_id AS b_id, e1.product AS prod, e1.id AS id, 
e2.bundle_id AS b2_id, e2.product AS prod2, e2.id AS id2,
e3.bundle_id AS b3_id, e3.product AS prod3, e3.id AS id3,
e4.bundle_id AS b4_id, e4.product AS prod4, e4.id AS id4,    
FROM `staging` AS e1
INNER JOIN `staging` AS e2 ON (e1.bundle_id = e2.bundle_id AND e1.id != e2.id)
INNER JOIN `staging` AS e3 ON (e2.bundle_id = e3.bundle_id AND e2.id != e3.id)
INNER JOIN `staging` AS e4 ON (e1.bundle_id = e4.bundle_id AND e3.id != e4.id)
WHERE e1.bundle_code = '10'
AND e2.bundle_code = '20'
AND e2.product = 'H'
AND e3.product != 'H'
AND e4.product != 'H'
```

This appears to work fine if there are four total results, but if there are three results then one set of data is a duplicate (in this case, it's id 1691):

```
b_id    prod    id      b2_id   prod2   id2     b3_id   prod3   id3     b4_id   prod4   id4
208768  NULL    1691    208768  H       1692    208768  NULL    1691    208768  L       1693
```

If I add in additional WHERE clauses to try and prevent this, it returns zero rows instead, so I'm thinking my JOIN syntax is off someplace.  Any ideas?

Comment: will the base entry always be null? also you show H, L, D for entries.  Will these be unique for each one?

Comment: Product is always NULL where bundle_code = 10, and always not NULL where bundle_code = 20. There should only ever be one H per bundle_code, and either one or two L's per bundle_code.  The last bit is what's giving me the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT e1.bundle_id AS b_id, e1.product AS prod, e1.id AS id, 
e2.bundle_id AS b2_id, e2.product AS prod2, e2.id AS id2,
e3.bundle_id AS b3_id, e3.product AS prod3, e3.id AS id3,
e4.bundle_id AS b4_id, e4.product AS prod4, e4.id AS id4,    
FROM `staging` AS e1
INNER JOIN `staging` AS e2 ON (e1.bundle_id = e2.bundle_id AND e1.id != e2.id)
LEFT JOIN `staging` AS e3 ON (e1.bundle_id = e3.bundle_id AND e2.id != e3.id AND e3.id != e1.id AND e3.product != 'H')
LEFT JOIN `staging` AS e4 ON (e1.bundle_id = e4.bundle_id AND e3.id != e4.id AND e4.id != e2.id AND e4.id != e1.id AND e4.product != 'H')
WHERE e1.bundle_code = '10'
AND e2.bundle_code = '20'
AND e2.product = 'H';
```

Comment: It doesn't - returns zero results. As I mentioned I've tried a couple of similar things and it always returns nothing.

Comment: GOt it.. remove the WHEREs and put them in the JOIN for the respective tables in the above query and it should work for you.

Comment: Do you mean: `INNER JOIN staging AS e2 ON (e1.bundle_id = e2.bundle_id AND e1.bundle_code = '10')`?

Comment: This, combined with GROUP BY, seems to have solved it.  Thanks!